# BadValueError: Indexed value message_text must be at most 1500 bytes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am storing HTML in the attribute of an entity. The problem I am facing now is that the size of the HTML can be bigger than 1500 bytes. Am I pushing the boundaries of Google Cloud Datastore ?

I am using TextProperty in my model

```
class Article(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    author = ndb.StringProperty()
    content = ndb.TextProperty()
    date_created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

**Question 1**

Should I look at storing html in Google Cloud Storage or some other options ?

**Question 2**

Is it possible to increase the size of the indexed value of a given entity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct to use a TextProperty for string values bigger than 1500 bytes, however TextProperty cannot be indexed and there is your problem.

> class TextProperty()
>
> A long string.
>
> Unlike StringProperty, a TextProperty value can be more than 1500
>   bytes long. **However, TextProperty values are not indexed and cannot be
>   used in filters or sort orders.**
>
> TextProperty values store text with a text encoding. For binary data,
>   use BlobProperty.
>
> If the text property is required, its value cannot be an empty string.

---

> Is it possible to increase the size of the indexed value of a given entity ?

No. It is possible to index short strings *because* they are short.

> Should I look at storing html in Google Cloud Storage or some other options ?

If it's just 1 html, I suggest you write it to a file.

You can of course also not index the TextProperty, if it's not really required.

Comment: Hey @tim-castelijns nice explanation in my case for `TextProperty` type also it's not allowing my large sized string to store in datastore. ndb is throwing exception saying `The value of property "{field name}" is longer than 1048487 bytes.` Any idea what can be done in this case ?